# Group by Pairs all textbox input vb.net 2010

Tags: input, split, textbox, vb.net-2010

I have a textbox, I want to group all input two by two.

Input: E5D3DFOXJFUIOXZJDFCNIUEBSKDLFJCNESODFKJ

I want to become: E5 D3 DF OX JF UI OX ZJ DF CN IU EB SK DL FJ CN ES OD FK J

How can I do that?

I have this function but it doesn't really work :

```
    For i As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Length - 2 To 2 Step -2
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(i, " ")
    Next
```

It gives me something like that :

```
E5D 3D FO XJ FU IO XZ JD FC NI UE BS KD LF JC NE SO DF KJ
```

or when the string is too long it's like that :

```
E5D 3D FO XJ FU IO XZ JD F C NI UE BS K D LF JC NE SO DF KJ
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the language switch to C#. Not particularly elegant, but the following code should work for both even and odd lengths of string

```
    string buffer = String.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i += 2)
    {
        // Exclude the case where 1 or 2 remaining chars here (no trailing space)
        if (textBox1.Text.Length - i > 2)
        {
            buffer += textBox1.Text.Substring(i, 2) + " ";
        }
        else
        {
            buffer += textBox1.Text.Substring(i);
        }
    }
    textBox1.Text = buffer;
```

Comment: Ok thanks you for the reply in Visual Basic 2010 it will be : 


        Dim buffer As String = [String].Empty

        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1 Step 2
            ' Exclude the case where 1 or 2 remaining chars here (no trailing space)
            If TextBox1.Text.Length - i > 2 Then
                buffer += TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 2) & " "
            Else
                buffer += TextBox1.Text.Substring(i)
            End If
        Next
        TextBox1.Text = buffer


K.N.A.82

Answer (score 0):

Thanls you for reply, C# or VB.net it's the same :-) in vb2010 it will be :

```
    Dim buffer As String = [String].Empty

    For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Length - 1 Step 2
        ' Exclude the case where 1 or 2 remaining chars here (no trailing space)
        If TextBox1.Text.Length - i > 2 Then
            buffer += TextBox1.Text.Substring(i, 2) & " "
        Else
            buffer += TextBox1.Text.Substring(i)
        End If
    Next
    TextBox1.Text = buffer
```

K.N.A.82.A.C.M